# Get mode passed to fopen from resource?

Tags: php, file, file-io

I'm trying to write very pedantic unit tests.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function foo($file) {
    if (is_string($file)) {
        if (!is_writable($file)) {
            throw new Exception('Cannot write to file');
        }
        $fp = fopen($file, 'wb');
    } elseif (is_resource($file)) {
        // **** How to check that $file is in wb mode? ****
        $fp = $file;
    }
    // Do stuff with $fp
}
```

How do I ensure that, given an arbitrary `resource`, it was a file opened with the `wb` flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[stream_get_meta_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) should help, it returns `mode` among other info about the passed resource.